# Landscape is not compiling to produce pdf if i use \input{chapters/ }

Tags: longtable, landscape

I'm writing my thesis by using `\input{chapters/..}` to add the chapters to the main `.tex`.

While the PDF is produced in a separate `.tex` file, it is not produced when I'm compiling the main file.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[font={bf,footnotesize},format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\small  % Switch from 12pt to 11pt; otherwise, table won't fit
%\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
%\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\begin{longtable}{lcccccc}
  \caption{Πλήρες \textlatin{BEKK} και Πλήρες Ασύμμετρο \textlatin{BEKK}}
  \hline
 Υπόδειγμα   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Πλήρες \textlatin{BEKK}} & &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Πλήρες Ασύμμετρο \textlatin{BEKK}} &  \\
 \hline
    Παράμετρος & Τιμή & Τυπικο Σφάλμα & \textlatin{T-test} & Τιμή & Τυπικο Σφάλμα & \textlatin{T-test} \\                       
    $A_{11}$ & 0,27815^{*} & (0,08599) & 3.2348 & 0,30954^{*} & (0,08544) & 3.6231 \\                       
    $A_{21}$ & -0,01736  & (0,12469) & -0.13919 & -0,02746  & (0,13102) & -0.20961 \\                       
    $A_{31}$ & -0,01882  & (0,07312) & -0.2574 & -0,00535  & (0,02728) & 2.41526 \\                     
    $A_{43}$ & -0,03004  & (0,18818) & -0.15965 & -0,01201  & (0,13625) & -0.08817 \\                       
    $A_{14}$ & 0,00557  & (0,03539) & 0.15731 & -0,01596  & (0,0382) & -0.41788 \\                      
    $A_{24}$ & -0,00684  & (0,01925) & -0.35518 & -0,04397  & (0,05226) & -0.84142 \\                       
    $A_{34}$ & -0,026  & (0,06569) & -0.39575 & -0,01394  & (0,03309) & -0.42116 \\                     
    $A_{44}$ & 0,22981^{*} & (0,09845) & 2.33427 & 0,22862^{*} & (0,08114) & 2.81776 \\                     
    $B_{11}$ & 0,89587^{*} & (0,05047) & 17.74975 & 0,18726  & (0,31355) & 0.59722 \\                       
    $B_{21}$ & -0,01315  & (0,12507) & -0.10513 & -0,02587  & (0,23578) & -0.10972 \\                       
    $B_{31}$ & -0,00846  & (0,07539) & -0.1122 & 0,00858  & (0,06704) & 0.12796     $G_{11}$ &       &       &       & 0,89361^{*} & (0,07974) & 11.20632 \\                        
    $G_{21}$ &       &       &       & 0,01606  & (0,03995) & 0.40188 \\    
    \hline                  
  \textlatin{loglikelihood} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Πλήρες \textlatin{BEKK}} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Πλήρες Ασύμμετρο \textlatin{BEKK}} &  \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{21936.7} &             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-21342.67} &  \\                                       
\hline                                   
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Check the file encoding, which might be UTF-8, instead of iso-8859-7

Comment: your question isn't very clear, you mention `\input` but your example code does not show any input.

Comment: It seems that if I use longtable Its not possible to use threeparttable afterwards. But anyway,I changed threeparttable with simple table and it's compiling.
@werner. I write in greek so I need that encording.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Use `threeparttablex` if you want to combine `threeparttable` and `longtable`, though I don't think this should be needed if you just want separate `threeparttable` and `longtable` in the same document (but I'm not certain as I've not tried this).